# Passing a reference as an argument and not naming it in Perl

Tags: perl

so I have something like this:

```
@result = myfun \@args;
```

I want to do something like this:

```
sub myfun{
foreach (@@_){ $_ = $_**2; } #foreach element the argument is referring to square the element
return @@_; # return the list that the argument is referring to
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. A function which receives a reference doesn't know or care if it's named or not. Your current function accepts a list, not a reference to a list. Strictly speaking `@_` is a name too, and there is no way to refer to something which doesn't have *any* name more than once.

Comment: `myfun, \@args` : did you mean `myfun( \@args )` ?

Comment: Note that `@_` is aliased to the variables in the caller, so if you modify that array you will also modify the corresponding variables in the caller, see [perldoc perlsub](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html) for more information

Comment: yes, I mean myfun \@args; without the , or alternatively myfun( \@args ), thanks.
Yes, @_ is an alias that contains a list of arguments. But I mean if the @_ contains only references, how to dereference them? How to tell perl, to pick an element of @_ and dereference it without creating more references or variables?

Comment: In your example `@_` contains only one reference `\@args` (not a list of references, but a reference to a list)

Comment: @_ is a list. It does not matter if it contains only one element, it is a list of references.

Comment: My question is, is there a way to shorten
foreach (@_){foreach (@$_){ $_=$_**2;}}
to something like @(@_[0]) or anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
my @args = 1..5;
my @result = myfun( \@args );
say for @result;

sub myfun{
    map {$_**2} @{$_[0]};
}
```

**Output**:

```
1
4
9
16
25
```

Answer (score 1):

As previously mentioned, one could simply use

```
sub myfun { map { $_ ** 2 } @{ $_[0] } }

my @args = 1..5;
say for myfun(\@args);
```

But one has to wonder why you wish to pass a reference. The following is simpler:

```
sub myfun { map { $_ ** 2 } @_ }

my @args = 1..5;
say for myfun(@args);
```

If you happen to have a reference on the outside, you can always "flatten" it there instead of in the sub.

```
sub myfun { map { $_ ** 2 } @_ }

my $args = [ 1..5 ];
say for myfun(@$args);
```

Answer (score 1):

> How to tell perl, to pick an element of @_ and dereference it without
>   creating more references or variables?

To dereference an element of `@_`, say `$_[0]`, you enclose it in `{}` and place that in any type of syntax where you would have a variable name (excluding the sigil).  E.g. `@{$_[0]}` instead of `@array` or `${$_[0]}[0]` instead of `$array[0]`.

See http://perlmonks.org?node=References+quick+reference for more examples.